# laravel deploy - RecursiveDirectoryIterator::hasChildren(): open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: php, laravel

i'm trying to deploy my laravel project.

i have this error:

```
RecursiveDirectoryIterator::hasChildren(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/navidade/access-logs) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/navidade:/usr/lib/php:/usr/php4/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php4/lib/php:/tmp)

in ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator.php (line 73)
```

what is the problem?

Comment: Deploy to a hoster? (Btw, `/usr/local/php4` are you using php4??) PHP is not allowed to access the folder `/home/navidade/access-logs`. If you can edit your `php.ini` you can add the path of your folder to the `open_basedir =` section. If you can't edit you'd need to use a path that is allowed - or change your hoster.

Comment: yes i am using a host. and my php version is 7.1

Comment: I found the solution:
moving the acess-logs folder to www folder makes it okey.